# How to fetch MySQL data without creating Object from Class in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to fetch data from MySQL without creating object from class

Normally I do something like

```
public ArrayList getInventoryByItemId(String ItemId) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
    String sql = "SELECT iid, i.uid, item_data, item_id, i.ctime, username, gender FROM Inventory i JOIN user u ON i.uid = u.uid WHERE item_id = '"+ItemId+"'";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rset.next()) {
        a = new Inventory(rset.getInt(1), rset.getInt(2), rset.getString(3), rset.getString(4), rset.getTimestamp(6), rset.getString(7), rset.getString(8));
        list.add(a);
    }
    return list;
}
```

the problem is because `Inventory` object does not have user data from the joined user table, I cannot create new `Inventory`.

I just want to automatically make an object where it has all the data attributes, that I can access using the column name.

Thank You

Comment: From your question it appears that your main issue is that `sql` is not returning any records due to unsatisfied join criteria. Is that right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you problem,

You can create new map(HashMap I reccomend) and put values using column name or index as key.
So, your list will be list of maps.

```
 while (rset.next()) {
        a = new HashMap<Integer,Object>();
        a.put(1,rset.getInt(1));
        ..........
        list.add(a);
    }
```

Or, If you know exact number of columns, you can user array instead of Map (it will be faster)

Comment: what type should list be? I tried HashMap list = new HashMap() but it says add(HashMap) is not good

Comment: List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

Comment: it works with this ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can read this article for future, it is reccomended to use generics.
http://www.myhomepageindia.com/index.php/2009/07/02/generics-in-java-5-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying, I take it that your query is not returning data because the inventory does not have the user data that it is being joined with. You need to modify your query to use a left outer join.

```
String sql = "SELECT iid, i.uid, item_data, item_id, i.ctime, username, gender FROM Inventory i LEFT JOIN user u ON i.uid = u.uid WHERE item_id = '"+ItemId+"'"
```

This will allow your query to return Inventory data even if the corresponding User data does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. You can use HashMaps to just store the column data.